# Why are suggested edits for deleted questions and answers visible even with less than 10,000 reputation?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Why are these edits still visible? Since the questions and answers can't be seen anymore to most users,
and the reviews for, say, late answers and close votes show "answer not found" or "question not found"
in place of the deleted answer or question, I assume this behavior for suggested edits is faulty. What do you think?

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/929764

Comment: Why should not the suggested edit be visible?

Comment: It's worth noting that the edit history of un-deleted posts is fully visible, so "delete" should *not* not be interpreted as "hide contents from the internet".